problem with nomenclature and abbreviation
A strange problem I suffer from
when the nomenclature appears in the table of contents of the thesis, it disappear from the the thesis; I can't find them
and vice versa, when it appears in the thesis, nomenclature disappears from the list of content

\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic,french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{acronym}
   
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tikz, lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage{calligra,frcursive,xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pagestyle{plain}
\linespread{1.3} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth }{0.3pt}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, linkcolor=blue,citecolor=red,urlcolor=blue}
%% itemize
\usepackage{enumitem}
%% table
\usepackage{tabulary,booktabs}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{1ex}
\usepackage[
singlelinecheck=false % <-- important
]{caption}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{physics}
\graphicspath{{./image/}}
\makenomenclature
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{1.5cm}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\timesr}{\fontfamily{artimes}\selectfont}
\let\times\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\times}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"02}
%------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
     
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Table of contents %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}\lhead{\textbf \footnotesize\it{Contents}} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\chead{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\rhead{}
\pagestyle{fancy}\lfoot{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\cfoot{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\rfoot{}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\tableofcontents 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% List of Figures %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of figures}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}\lhead{\textbf \footnotesize\it{List of Figures}} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\chead{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\rhead{}
\pagestyle{fancy}\lfoot{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\cfoot{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\rfoot{}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% List of Tables %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of tables}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}\lhead{\textbf \footnotesize\it{List of Tables}} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\chead{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\rhead{}
\pagestyle{fancy}\lfoot{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\cfoot{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\rfoot{}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% List of Abbreviations %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}\lhead{\textbf \footnotesize\it{}} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\chead{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\rhead{}
\pagestyle{fancy}\lfoot{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\cfoot{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\rfoot{}
\pagenumbering{gobble} % To suppress numbering 

\newpage
\nomenclature{A}{Cross-sectional area of the beam}
\nomenclature{B}{Gradient matrix}
\nomenclature{D}{Matrix of material}
 
\printnomenclature

\chapter*{Abbreviation}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{CAD}{Computer Aided Design}

\end{acronym}

